# best way of setting up 12 product pages in AngularJS with dynamic routing and templating

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm somewhat new to AngularJS so I'd like to know whats the best way to architect the products section of my app.

So I have a main product page which will list and link to all my 12 products. Then each ind. product page will need to have the same format (i.e. product description, color, height etc.). This data will *not* be coming from a backend source. Its just plain HTML.

Whats the best way of setting things up to maximize code reuse? I'm thinking I want to do for the routing -  `/products/products.html` to list all products and then something like `/products/product1.html`  for an ind. product.

How can I make this all work in AngularJS?

Thanks!

Comment: /products for the list page - /products/:productID for a specific product

Comment: would it be possible to do this then: ```templateUrl: 'views/:productID',```?

Comment: @SunnyDay If the answer below has helped you then please select it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For routing you will need to use the ng-view directive in your HTML. The simplest way I can think of is to create a div on the main page and assign it the directive ng-view. Then your Javascript file create a the routing. Below is a sample code just for reference purpose.

```
   // YOUR HTML
   <main class="cf" ng-view>
   </main>

  // YOUR JAVASCRIPT
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'appControllers']);
  var appControllers  =  angular.module('appControllers', []);
  myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){

  $routeProvider.
  when("/products1", { templateUrl: "views/products1.html"}).
  when("/products", { templateUrl: "views/products2.html"}).
  when("/products3", { templateUrl: "views/products3.html"}).
  otherwise({
    redirectTo: "/login"});

  }]);
```